# How can i map this requiremnt for oneToMany

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, mapping, one-to-many

```
public class UserOUData {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String UserEmail;
@OneToMany(mappedBy="usersId")
private Long orgUnitPathId;
}
@Entity
@Table(name="Ou")
public class OU {

    @Id
    private long id;
    
    private String name;
    
    private String path;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="orgUnitPathId")
    private Collection<UserOUData> usersId;
    }
```

i have tried some of posible examples
but stil i am facing the issue

**Illegal attempt to map a non collection as a @OneToMany, @ManyToMany or @CollectionOfElements: cloudcodes.schema.generator.model.UserOUData.orgUnitPathId**

```
    private Long orgUnitPathId;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="orgUnitPathId")
    private Collection<UserOUData> usersId;
```

can anyone help me out with this
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have one organizational unit which can have multiple users, so you need `OneToMany` relationship on the organization unit:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Ou")
public class OU {
    @Id
    private long id;
    
    private String name;
    private String path;
    
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "organizationalUnit")
    private Collection<UserOUData> usersData;
}
```

For the `UserOUData` you need a `ManyToOne`, since multiple users can be part of the same `OU`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="UserOUData")
public class UserOUData {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String UserEmail;
    
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ou_id")
    private OU organizationalUnit;
}
```

This setup assumes that you would want to make the connection bidirectional between `OU` and `UserOUData`.

Comment: Thanks for answering @Ervin Szilagyi but in UserOuData table the feild represents Long orgId not the object of OU .